# Wake On Lan not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, wakeonlan

I'm trying to set up wol on a laptop connected to a tp-link adapter by an ethernet cable. The PC that sends the magic packet is also connected to this adapter.

I've already followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan#Setting_Up_Wake-on-LAN) to enable wol on the interface and to make sure it is active, since `sudo ethtool <NIC>` outputs a `g`.

WOL is also enabled on the BIOS as seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjbVd.png).

I'm sending the packet trough a Windows 10 machine with the wolcmd tool using the following command:

```
wolcmd f0:76:1c:7a:c3:a7 192.168.1.143 255.255.255.0 7
```

This command outputs:

> Wake On Lan signal sent to Mac Address f0:76:1c:7a:c3:a7 via Broadcast
> Address 192.168.1.255 on port 7

Android apps that should automatically detect the available wakeable devices aren't able to pick up the laptop either.
I also tried to find the packet on wireshark scnanning the trafic on the ethernet interface on both the pc that sends the packet and the laptop but it didn't seem to appear... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please describe what exactly is the "tp-link adapter"?

Comment: When the machine reboots, are the WOL settings still in place or are they reset?

Comment: @matigo they are still in place. I believe they are persistent

Comment: @ChanganAuto the model is tp-link av500. It's a wifi repeater. Not sure if the devices need to be connected to an actual router for this to work, that's why I mentioned this